# Why this code is showing error?

Tags: javascript

The 2nd line is showing error.

```
"ReferenceError: specialTrick is not defined
    at CoolGuy.showoff (<anonymous>:23:40)
    at <anonymous>:31:5
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)"
```

```js
class CoolGuy {
    specialTrick = null;

    CoolGuy( trick ) {
        specialTrick = trick
    }

    showOff() {
        console.log( "Here's my trick: ", specialTrick );
    }

}

Joe = new CoolGuy("rope climbing");
Joe.shoeOff();
```

Comment: Maybe you should define specialTrick

Comment: Maybe try `var specialTrick` (or `let specialTrick` in ES6)

Comment: https://webkit.org/blog/1544/web-inspector-understanding-stack-traces/

Comment: See also `.showOff` , `.shoeOff`

Answer (score 5):

1. You should use the `constructor` function (and not a function with the same name).
2. You can't set members inside the class definition (you set them inside the constructor), using `this`.
3. You had a typo in the `showOff` function.

More information [in the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Here is the fix:

```js
class CoolGuy {

    constructor( trick ) {
        this.specialTrick = trick
    }

    showOff() {
        console.log( "Here's my trick: ", this.specialTrick );
    }
}

Joe = new CoolGuy("rope climbing");
Joe.showOff();
```